# lex:converting hex to dec

Tags: lex

I am trying to build a simple lexical analysis with flex and bison, but I have a problem with converting hex to dec in my lexer.l.
Here are my codes.

> hex (0)([x]|[X])([0-9][A-Fa-f])+

> {hex}{count++;printf("%d\t(hex,%s)\n",count,yytext);}

Comment: Please be clearer about the problem. What is it that you expect? What is it that your program produces? Why does that surprise you?

Comment: I am trying to build a simple lexical analysis with lex, but during the process I had a problem with converting hex to dec in my lexer.l. For example I input a '0x1f' , it can give me a number '31'.

Comment: "I have a problem" provides no useful information. In order to help you, we need to understand what the problem is. Maybe your problem is that you don't understand how strings and integers are represented inside the computer. Maybe your problem is the format of your lex file (there's a space missing in the line of code you included but maybe that's just a typo.) Or one of a zillion other possible problems. Please be specific. (And maybe read [ask].)

Comment: just when I want to build a lexical analysis, while I input '0x1f', my lex file can give me the output '31', now I can only scan to identify that '0x1f' is a hexadecimal number, but I can't covert this hexadecimal number  into a decimal number. I don't know how to convert.

Comment: `strtol` in the standard library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ohhh！I solved the problem! I just need to add two functions like c program and change the type of my output.

```
{hex} {count++;printf("%d\t(hex,%d)\n",count,hextodec(yytext));}
{oct} {count++;printf("%d\t(oct,%d)\n",count,octtodec(atoi(yytext)));}



int octtodec(int oct){
 int dec=0,pos=0;
 while (oct){
     int a=oct%10;
     dec += a * pow(8,pos);
     pos++;
     oct /= 10;
 }
 return dec;}

 int hextodec(char *hex){
 int dec=0,pos=0;
 int len;
 len=strlen(hex);
 for (int i =2;i<len;i++){
     if(hex[i]>='a'&&hex[i]<='f'){
         dec=dec+(hex[i]-'a'+10)*pow(16,len-i-1);
     }
     else if(hex[i]>='A'&&hex[i]<='F'){
         dec=dec+(hex[i]-'A'+10)*pow(16,len-i-1);
     }
     else{
         dec+=(hex[i]-'0')*pow(16,len-i-1);
     }
 }
 return dec;}
```